# incorrect work HTML5 Sortable lists, ajax post and disabled item

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using a neat sort plugin for jQuery, HTML5 Sortable http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/ and would like to disable some items.

I add `class="disabled"` to `<li>`-tag and add `items: ':not(.disabled)'` to javasript, but it does't work...

By the way if remove `$('.sortable').sortable().bind()` function from javasript, then everything works correctly...

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
<ul id="disabled" class="sortable">
    <li data-id="1" class="disabled">One</li>
    <li data-id="2">Two</li>
    <li data-id="3">Three</li>
    <li data-id="4" class="disabled">Four</li>
    <li data-id="5">Five</li>
</ul>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate', function() {
    var dataIDList = $('.sortable li').map(function(){  return $(this).data("id"); }).get().join(",");
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url: "post.php?dataIDList="+dataIDList });
    }); 

    $('#disabled').sortable({
        items: ':not(.disabled)'
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Christina, try to modify your code like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.sortable').sortable({
        items: ':not(.disabled)'
    }).bind('sortupdate', function() {
    var dataIDList = $('.sortable li').map(function(){  return $(this).data("id"); }).get().join(",");
    $.ajax({ type: "POST",  url: "post.php?dataIDList="+dataIDList });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you're calling the sortable at the start:

`$('.sortable').sortable().bind('sortupdate`...

You need to change it to read:

`$('.sortable').bind('sortupdate`...